# Serving content from S3 securely

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm writing a web application in go and I'm using amazon s3 to store all the user files, this include the profile pics and text and audio files.

However I'm struggling to understand what will be the correct way to do this securely. What I was thinking is after making sure the request comes from an authenticated user with access to the requested file, just use the aws go library to fetch the file and write it to the http request.

Something like this:

```
import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "io"
)

func serveFile(file string, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    svc := s3.New(session.New(), aws.NewConfig().WithRegion(config.AWS.Region))

    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String("Bucket name"),
    Key:    aws.String(file),
    }

    resp, err := svc.GetObject(params)
    n, err := io.Copy(w, resp.Body)

}
```

I don't have much experience working with AWS so I'm not sure this is even a good approach, but it works. Is this a good way to do it, for a production server? Is there a better, more reliable way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method can work. But it relies on requests being proxied through your client.

The recommend way is to use signed urls. This creates a url that is valid for a time period that you specify that allows the end user to download a file directly from S3.

Your key is not exposed as the url contains just a signature.

Comment: But wouldn't this allow content to be downloaded by unauthenticated users if the url gets compromised, even if just for a small period of time?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you stick to SSL you would significantly limit the risk. Short of man in the middle attacks anyway.

Comment: And what are the downsides of proxying the requests through my web service? Apart from the obvious of using more resources on the server.

Comment: Using more resources on the server (and network bandwidth) is probably the biggest downside by far. Reading files from S3 into memory, across multiple simultaneous clients, has a non-negligible impact on your server.

Comment: @elithrar I agree with this, but the impact on the server will be the same as if I hosted everything locally, right?

Comment: Not quite. Locally your file-system cache might cache regularly accessed files; pulling from S3 requires a network request out (adds latency), processing, and then a copy to the ResponseWriter.  I suggest testing, but using S3's signed URLs is nearly always the way to go.

Comment: @elithrar Thanks. Currently the official go library for AWS `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3` doesn't support signed URLs at this point but I can always use the web API or the goamz library by canonical.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution for following reasons:

- The fact that you are using S3 is transparent to the client. In other words, the client doesn't need to or should know that you are using S3 in backend, unless there is a good reason for this.
- Tomorrow if you want to move your data from S3 to some other data store, you only need to change your server code. The client doesn't need to update.
- AWS credentials aren't exposed to client, hence more security.

Comment: 1) There are few storage options as highly available, scalable and performant as S3
2) It's easy enough to switch backends all the signed url code does is tell the client where to grab the resource from. It doesn't matter if its in S3 or some other storage server
3) The AWS credentials aren't ever exposed to the client. The server grabs a signed URL which is only valid for a certain amount of time (default 15 minutes). If you use IAM roles for your server you never even have to put your credentials onto your server further reducing the risk of leaking credentials